# O que é o AntiForgeryToken?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, segurança

O que é o `AntiForgeryToken` e para que ele serve em uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

É um [método](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.antiforgerytoken?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) que gera e insere no HTML gerado na *view* um código para evitar que se falsifique o envio de dados para o servidor.

Quando se usa este método ele insere algo assim:

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden"
    value="saTFWpkKN0BYazFtN6c4YbZAmsEwG0srqlUqqloi/fVgeV2ciIFVmelvzwRZpArs" />
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/AntiForgeryToken.cs).

Quando o formulário for enviado com este código é possível validar se foi gerado pela sessão atual. O atributo [`ValidateAntiForgeryToken`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.validateantiforgerytokenattribute?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) é usado para validar no controlador.

Ele resolve alguns tipos de ataque como [CSRF](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery), mas não todos.

Comment: Sensacional @bigown cada dia mais aprendendo com suas respostas.

Comment: ValidateAntiForgeryToken faz sentido usar em uma Web Api?

Answer (score 7):

Caso vc precisa passar as informações via AJAX com jQuery pode fazer assim:~

```javascript
var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();

$.ajax({
    url: "/Controller/Action",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        __RequestVerificationToken: token,
        IdAnuncio: $("#IdAnuncio").val(),
        Quantidade: quantidade,
        ValorCompra: valorCompra.toFixed(2)
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score -3):

No entanto, para ser usado vc deve chamar o método que insere o token na página html. "@Html.AntiForgeryToken()"