# Como passar parâmetro para controller MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Como passar o texto ou o índice de uma `DropDownList` para o `Controller` ao pressionar um botão?

Tentei usando `@model` e não consegui.
Tentei adicionando o `[HttpPost]` no `Controller` e usando o botão do tipo `submit` e nem assim funcionou.

**Controller**:

```
public ActionResult Pesquisar(string _ddl)
{
  string opcaoDdl = _ddl;
  return View();
}
```

**Index**:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ddlListaUnidades", new SelectList(ViewBag.listaUnidades), new { @class = "dllListaUnidades" })

<div class="botoesfiltrodiv">

    <input class="filtro-buttons" type="button" value="Limpar" />
    <input class="filtro-buttons" type="button" value="Pesquisar" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Pesquisar", "UnidadeAtendimento")'" />

</div>
```

Quando aperto o botão, ele até chama o `controller`, mas não consigo passar o parâmetro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O paramento do `Controller` tem que ter o mesmo nome da `tag` [html](/questions/tagged/html) gerada no caso `ddlListaUnidades`:

```
[HttpPost()]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
public ActionResult Pesquisar(string ddlListaUnidades)
{    
    string opcaoDdl = ddlListaUnidades;    

    return View();
}
```

e na parte `<form>` tem que utilizar assim:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Pesquisar","UnidadeAtendimento", FormMethod.Post)) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.DropDownList("ddlListaUnidades", new SelectList(ViewBag.listaUnidades),
                   new { @class = "dllListaUnidades" })    
    <div class="botoesfiltrodiv">    
        <input class="filtro-buttons" type="button" value="Limpar" />
        <input class="filtro-buttons" type="submit" value="Pesquisar" />    
    </div>

}
```

<sub>***Referencias e Leituras:***</sub>

- [ASP.NET MVC Model Binding and Data Annotation](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/551576/ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding-and-Data-Annotation)
- [Para que é usado Bind(Include = “Propriedade”)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45459/para-que-%C3%A9-usado-bindinclude-propriedade)
- [O que é o AntiForgeryToken?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86063/o-que-%C3%A9-o-antiforgerytoken)
- [ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateantiforgerytokenattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)
- [HtmlHelper.AntiForgeryToken Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd470175(v=vs.118).aspx)
- [All ASP.NET MVC Forms Need To Include Html.AntiForgeryToken() For Security](http://peterkellner.net/2014/05/19/asp-net-mvc-forms-need-include-html-antiforgerytoken-security/)
- [Prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) using ASP.NET MVC’s AntiForgeryToken() helper](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/)
- [Send and validate an ASP.NET AntiForgeryToken as a request header.](https://nozzlegear.com/blog/send-and-validate-an-asp-net-antiforgerytoken-as-a-request-header)

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno Virgilio, mas eu já havia feito esse teste antes, e mesmo assim não funcionou. Acabei de testar de novo, e ainda sim não funcionou.

Comment: @EvandroSilva eu vi mais problems e editei a resposta, dá uma verificada por favor

Comment: vou tentar, embora eu ja tenha tentado desta maneira, mas não havia inserido o @Html.AntiForgeryToken(), vou testar e ja lhe dou um retorno. Obrigado

Comment: Muito obrigado, problema resolvido. Realmente era a questão o AntiForgeryToken