# Codificação de caracteres especiais antes de ir para a base de dados SQL

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

**Estou trabalhando com SQL Server 2008 e IIS7 para hospedar o meu website MVC.**

Por questões de segurança, o website no qual trabalho neste momento, não permite que `strings` com caracteres especiais como '<' ou '>' provenientes de uma `<textarea>` sejam enviadas para a base de dados.

Como posso codificar esses caracteres e depois descodifica-los depois de buscar a string à base de dados? Quero conseguir fazer algo do tipo:

1. Codificar caracteres especiais na *RazorView* numa string usando JavaScript
2. Enviar a string codificada (que não tem os caracteres especiais) usando um POST para o *Controller* do *MVC*
3. Buscar a string à base de dados e descodificar, também, na *view*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não precisa nada disso. Basta marcar o *Model* ou *ViewModel* com [`[AllowHtml]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
[AllowHtml]
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public String MeuTextoHtml { get; set; }
```

Comment: O Data Anotattion `AllowHtml` previni ataques XSS?

Comment: Ele e o [`[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateantiforgerytokenattribute(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: Entendi +1. Aqui tem uma [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86063/o-que-%C3%A9-o-antiforgerytoken) interessante sobre o assunto.

Comment: e isso previne a execução de código inserido pela input? (ex. SQL injection)

Comment: @ihavenokia Se você usa Entity Framework, sim.

Comment: sim uso, obrigado ;)

Comment: assim que testar a sua solução e certificar-me que funciona como o esperado, vou aceitar a sua resposta como a mais correta

Comment: Se houver mais dúvidas sobre como usar, é só perguntar ;)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

Primeiro implementa a função abaixo, para criar um elemento e pegar o seu html

```
function HtmlEncode(s)
{
    var el = document.createElement("div");
    el.innerText = el.textContent = s;
    s = el.innerHTML;
    el.remove();
    return s;
}
```

Depois no seu POST você codifica a string e envia

```
var conteudo=HtmlEncode($("#MinhaTextArea").val())
$.ajax({
    url: '/Meucontrole/MinhaAction',
    method:"Post",
    data:{parametro:conteudo},
    success: function (d) {
        //TODO:;
    }

})
```

**Controller**

No seu controler você irá receber a string codificada no parâmetro `parametro` , para decodificar utilize `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()` e para codificar novamente 
`System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(t)`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MinhaAction(string parametro)
{
    var decodificado = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(parametro);

    //TODO:;

    var codificado = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(decodificado);
    return View();
}
```